# Timestamp update DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic, timestamp, db2

I would like to update query for records between 24 hours since the specific date and time. The current query works fine, except I need to update two timestamps manually. I am looking to reduce timestamps number to one or replace it with dynamic expression, so it will minimize human error if possible.

Current query looks like this:

```
SELECT timestamp 
FROM table
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2023-01-18-06.00.00.000000' AND '2023-01-19-06.00.00.000000'
```

I have been trying multiple recommended options but it does not work yet:

```
WHERE timestamp > '2023-01-19-06.00.00.000000' - 24 HOURS
WHERE timestamp > '2023-01-19-06.00.00.000000' – ‘24 HOURS’
WHERE timestamp ('2023-01-19-06.00.00.000000' - 24 HOURS)
WHERE timestamp > '2023-01-19-06.00.00.000000' - '24.00.00.000000'
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2023-01-04-06.00.00.000000' AND INTERVAL - 24 HOURS
WHERE timestamp > CURRENT DATE - 24 HOURS
WHERE timestamp ('2023-01-19' - 1 DAY, ('06.00.00.000000' - 24 HOURS))
```

Could anyone let me know what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'2023-01-19-06.00.00.000000' - 24 HOURS is near, but incorrect because DB2 doesn't see the first value as a timestamp but as a string even if it makes the automatic cast in the working query. so what you have to do is to tell it is a timestamp, because you add a duration

with the `timestamp` keyword

```
WHERE yourtimestamp > timestamp '2023-01-19-06.00.00.000000' - 24 HOURS
```

or the `timestamp` function

```
WHERE yourtimestamp > timestamp('2023-01-19-06.00.00.000000') - 24 HOURS
```

or this notation

```
WHERE yourtimestamp > '2023-01-19-06.00.00.000000'::timestamp - 24 HOURS
```

if you're not using DB2LUW or an old version, one or more option may not be available

i suggest you try something like this

```
SELECT timestamp 
FROM table cross join (values timestamp '2023-01-19-06.00.00.000000') as ref (stamp)
WHERE timestamp between ref.stamp - 24 hours and ref.stamp
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the two upper suggestions worked fine for me. The only issue now is that retrieved records include timestamps after 6 am as well, so it now 24 hours before timestamp plus hours left till EOD. Could you please advice?

Comment: @Narimanm can you edit your question and add the real query ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot add real query, but I would like to update query for records within 24 hours from specific date and time, let’s say between 6AM yesterday and  today.
Original query:
SELECT timestamp FROM table 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2023-01-19-06.00.00.000000' AND '2023-01-20-06.00.00.000000' 
New query:
WHERE mytimestamp > timestamp ('2023-01-20-06.00.00.000000') - 24 HOURS
New query does not stop at 6AM today, but also include all records for the same day after 6 am, which is more than 24 hours. Is there any way to limit query to 24 hours from specific timestamp?

Comment: @Narimanm you have to tell the is an upper limit, for example by adding `and mytimestamp < timestamp '2023-01-20-06.00.00.000000'`

Answer (score 0):

For the past 24hrs, as implied by your example

> `WHERE timestamp > CURRENT DATE - 24 HOURS`

You'd want to use `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` not `CURRENT DATE`

For a specific period, you'll always need two dates specified in the `WHERE` clause like so
`WHERE timestamp BETWEEN startTs AND endTs`

For a specific 24hr period from a given starting timestamp, you can do something like so:
`WHERE timestamp BETWEEN startTs AND startTs + 24 hours`

You can define `startTs` as a global variable, and use it in your `select`

```
create variable startTs timestamp default('2023-01-18 06:00:00.000');

SELECT timestamp 
FROM table
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN startTs AND startTs + 24 hours;
```

Or you could use a table value constructor to store it for use...

```
WITH tmp (startTime) AS (
    VALUES (timestamp('2023-01-19 06:00:00.000'))
) 
select timestamp from table
where timestamp between (select startTime from tmp limit 1) 
                   and (select startTime + 2 hours from tmp limit 1);
```

Depending on your use case, it might be worthwhile to encapsulate the statement as a stored procedure or a user defined table function (UDTF)...

Comment: Thank you Charles. I appreciate your suggestions.